# hair color isn't changing and stays white

Tags: particles

i created the hair of the character using blender render, and then use cycles render to color the hair, but the hair color isn't changing whatever i do. but in the tutorials that i've watched, which i followed exactly, the hair of their character is changing. what do i need to do? is there an easier way to color the hair using blender render and not cycles render?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use both the blender render and Cycles in the same scene? You will need to use different scenes if you wish to use different renderers for different parts of the model.

Comment: @RayMairlot, nvm i already fixed it, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

i got it [image]

particles -> render -> choose a material slot